# Perl statements separated by commas?

Tags: perl, quicksort

In this modified quick sort algorithm I'm dissecting/rewriting as part of a personal project, in Perl:

```
sub quick_sort {
    my @a = @_;
    return @a if @a < 2;
    my $p = splice @a, int( $#a / 2 ), 1;
    (
        quick_sort( grep $_ < $p, @a ),
        $p,
        quick_sort( grep $_ >= $p, @a ),
    );
}

print "Enter a list of numbers, separated by commas (e.g. 2,5,1,7): ";
my @a = split ",", <STDIN>;
@a = quick_sort(@a);
chomp(@a);
print "@a\n";
```

I am perplexed as to what this statement, or rather, group of statements separated by commas (I guess?) does:

```
quick_sort(grep $_ < $p, @a),
$p,
quick_sort(grep $_ >= $p, @a);
```

I don't even know what that's called, so googling "perl statements separated by commas" and the like has turned up nothing useful. I've experimented by separating them by semicolons, but the output is incorrect when I try that. What is this called, and what is it doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a recursive call to your subroutine. This is what it really does:

```
sub quick_sort {

## Grabs the list passed from the main body in to an array a
my @a = @_;

## If the scalar value of array is less than 2 
## then no sorting is needed so return the array as is
return @a if @a < 2;

## If not then grab one element which is from the middle of the array
my $p = splice (@a, int($#a / 2), 1);

## Call your method in recursion with list of 3 elements, first being an element smaller
## than the sliced, the element obtained from slice and an element
## greater than or equal to the sliced one
quick_sort(grep $_ < $p, @a), $p, quick_sort(grep $_ >= $p, @a);
```

}

Since [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) is a destructive function, at each iteration your array will shrink to a point where it will meet the following condition and exit.

```
return @a if @a < 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answers, but this one was the most detailed. Thanks Jaypal :) I get it now.

Comment: Where is comma-separated statements support documented?

Answer (score 2):

Those three last lines form a statement whose result is a list:

```
quick_sort(grep $_ < $p, @a), $p, quick_sort(grep $_ >= $p, @a);
```

That list is the result of the subroutine. If you use a semmicolon then the result of the subroutine would be:

```
quick_sort(grep $_ >= $p, @a);
```

which would be incorrect.

Comment: This was a great answer too - thanks for contributing! Helped me learn something new :)